# Create temporary sheets in excel to perform calculations

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, I have searched and read similar threads and I have tried the solutions that were proposed and solved the other people's problem but it hasn't worked in my case.

I basically want to create temporary excel sheet where I want to do all the calculations in the back-end and display only the output to the user in the front-end sheet.

Can anyone tell me how do I go got creating the temporary sheets and deleting them as soon as numbers are copied in the front-end sheet i.e. the sheet that user will see.

My main motive is not let the user see the various calculations that are happening in the back-end.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why isn't it working? Unless you can provide us with a clear, specific problem then this question will remain too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is what I mean when I say 'Too Broad'. If your question has a multitude of equally-correct answers (and it does in this case) then it's hard to tell which answer is the _best_ answer and our entire voting system falls apart. I'd really recommend you go back and look through the site tour that you skipped when creating your account, you'll even get a shiny bronze badge for doing so. Looking through [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would also be advisable if you still don't understand what I'm getting at.

Comment: Sure. Thanks I shall follow it next time on.

Answer (score 5):

you can create a temp sheet in VBA by using
`Sheets.Add.Name = "Temp Sheet"` or any other name really
and after you calculations done on it, delete it with
`Sheets("Temp Sheet").Delete`
bear in mind if your alerts are on it will prompt user to agree to delete the sheet, you can avoid that by using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before deleting and follow by `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to hide one sheet to perform calculations instead of creating temporary sheet.

Let's say you have input sheet, where user input his data. Another sheet is hidden. There the calculations are performed.

How to hide Sheet?

Go to VBA Code editor window (ALT+F11). Select sheet you want to hide. In a "Properties" window choose option: SheetHidden. Now, you can copy data from hidden sheet into destination sheet via using macro.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("HiddenSheetName").Range("A1:C56").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("VisibleSheetName").Range("A66:C106").PasteSecial xlValues
```

Note: i wrote above code straight from my head. Didn't tested!

Comment: Could you accept useful/working solution as an answer ?

Answer (score -1):

Sample code to create temp sheet:

```
Sub Sample()

Dim TempSheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Goto ErrorHandler:

Set TempSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
TempSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden

'Do the calculations

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TempSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ErrorHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```